# How to find Length of characters in MS SQL Server 2008 excluding the length of column name being given?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider below example:

```
Declare @Email varchar(90) = 'aaa@abcdefghighijklmnopqrstufdghfhfhfhgggfhfghgfbdfghhgdfhffdgfdgdsdfgfdgfdgdfgfdgdfgdfgdfffsdgffgdfgvwxyzsderkslwotsneiwnsyr.com'

IF(len(@Email) > 89)
Select 'Length of Email should not be greater than 90 - Error Message'
else
Select 'Correct email'
```

It works fine. However, when I implement the same logic in Stored Procedure. It doesn't work.

Note: @Email is simply declare. I have Email column in one of my table, say, "BulkImport" with datatype varchar(90). User can input incorrect format, length can be anything.

Hence, I want to find out its length if > 90 and validate it from sql.

Actual Code in Stored Procedure which doesn't work and throws and error 'Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid...' is given below:

```
Select 
    ISNULL(BI.Email, '')  ColumnName,
    'Length of Email sholud not be greater than 90'
From 
    BulkImport BI
Where 
    ISNULL(LEN(BI.Email), '') > 89
```

"I am well aware that, since Length of column "Email" is varchar(90), I am getting internal error However, I want to replace internal error with validation, which any user can understand."

Any solution to these or any substitute to LEN function in SQL will be more helpful.

Here's my code

```
public void UpdateBulkImportTable(Process process, eType objectType, DataTable sourceTable)
{
    bool _releaseProcess = false;
    if (process == null)
    {
        process = DataAccessManager.NewProcess(); _releaseProcess = true;
    }
    else process.ClearParameters();

    try
    {
        if(_releaseProcess) process.BeginTransaction();
        process.UpdateBulkData(objectType, sourceTable);
        if (_releaseProcess) process.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (process != null && _releaseProcess) process.RollbackTransaction();
        throw new ValidationException(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (process != null && _releaseProcess) process.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: First example returns one row regardless if the email is valid, the SP example returns a row only if the email is invalid. sounds like you changed the validation logic, you should expect something to break.. you should show your application code also.

Comment: the above query shouldn't return an error, yes an insert will return an error if you try to insert a value longer than 90 character in a column with length less than 90 character. can you show the insert statement that is throwing the error, sql server has `TRY CATCH` blocks like any other programming language for error handling and yes you can raise a user-friendly error message if the `email` column fails the validation.

Comment: I suggest using DATALENGTH instead of LEN. LEN misses out on valid empty string characters like trailing spaces, line breaks and line feeds etc. DATALENGTH measures the actual size of the string no matter which characters are used.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the last line into from

```
Where 
ISNULL(LEN(BI.Email), '') > 89
```

into

```
Where 
LEN(ISNULL(BI.Email, '')) > 89
```

Comment: Thanks. But, its not working. My front end code in C# is:

Comment: public void UpdateBulkImportTable(Process process, eType objectType, DataTable sourceTable)
        {
            bool _releaseProcess = false;

            if (process == null)
            {
                process = DataAccessManager.NewProcess();
                _releaseProcess = true;
            }
            else
                process.ClearParameters();

Comment: try
            {
                if(_releaseProcess)
                    process.BeginTransaction();

                process.UpdateBulkData(objectType, sourceTable);

                if (_releaseProcess)
                    process.CommitTransaction();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (process != null && _releaseProcess)
                    process.RollbackTransaction();

                throw new ValidationException(ex.Message);
            }

Comment: finally
            {
                if (process != null && _releaseProcess)
                    process.Release();
            }
        }

Comment: So you are having the issue when calling BulkInsert from a c# app?

Comment: Is that so? Because, when I am using:                                             Select 
 BI.Email ColumnName,
 'Email not in correct format. (ex.- test@testmail.com)'
From
 BulkImport BI
Where 
 BI.Email Not like '%[a-z,0-9,_,-]%%@[a-z,0-9,_,-]%.[a-z][a-z]%'         It works very fine with proper validation.

Comment: I don't know, you posted the code, so I assume that's where you're having issues?